# DRY integer float converter ruby on rails/ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, digit

I have NoDataBase calculator app. It takes digit parameters from view, made calculations in controller with some methods and return answer. The issue is to show correct answer in view. I need to show exact float or integer. 
I made some convertation, but it seems to looks ugly.
I wondering, how to implement DRY converter.

Links:

[interest_calculator/index.html.erb](https://github.com/tjai89/calculator_project/blob/master/app/views/interest_calculator/index.html.erb)

[interest_calculator_controller.rb](https://github.com/tjai89/calculator_project/blob/master/app/controllers/interest_calculator_controller.rb)

[number_to_number spec tests](https://github.com/tjai89/calculator_project/blob/master/spec/features/interest_calculator_number_to_number_spec.rb)

[persent_from_number spec tests](https://github.com/tjai89/calculator_project/blob/master/spec/features/interest_calculator_persent_from_number_spec.rb)

Rounding of float to 10 characters

```
# If accepted parameter is integer, then it shows in view as 5, when it
# is float, it shows as 5.1  
@first_0   = params[:a_0].to_f % 1 != 0 ? params[:a_0].to_f : params[:a_0].to_i
@second_0  = params[:b_0].to_f % 1 != 0 ? params[:b_0].to_f : params[:b_0].to_i
@first_1   = params[:a_1].to_f % 1 != 0 ? params[:a_1].to_f : params[:a_1].to_i
@second_1  = params[:b_1].to_f % 1 != 0 ? params[:b_1].to_f : params[:b_1].to_i  


integer_decimal_converter(@first_0, @second_0, @first_1, @second_1)
```

Comment: _"exact float"_ – that's unintentionally funny ;-)

Comment: Within reasonable limits

Comment: You should convert the output, not the input. `2 * 0.5` results in `1.0`, although you probably want to display `1`.

Comment: In view result shows as <p id="answer">Number <%= first_0 %> of the number<%= second_0 %> = <%= result_0 %>% </p> so i need to show current numbers first and second as well.

Comment: There is also goin to be a multiple calculations in a view, so put so many logic in views is not a good idea.

Comment: Use a helper: `Number <%= format(first_0) %> of the number <%= format(second_0) %> = <%= format(result_0) %>`

Comment: Can you show `integer_decimal_converter` method?

Comment: @Gerry thats the point, i have non

Comment: @KirillZhuravlov could you explain your problem a little more detailed? `params` has four keys, `a_0`, `b_0` and `a_1`, `b_1` – what is their meaning? What kind of calculation are you trying to perform based on these values? And how does your output look like?

Comment: @Stefan I have Interest Calculator project. It calculates 2 different scenarios. 1 - How many percent is one number from another. 2 - How much is a percentage of the number. It handles all calculations in one view, from one controller InterestCalculatorController. It takes parameters from form and perform calculations through methods. But ruby has a specific way of making calculations. It rounds every calculation to integer. I avoid this behaviour with manipulations shoved above. But I want to DRY them.

Comment: You you give a concrete example of the input(s) and output(s) for different scenarios, i.e. actual numbers?

Comment: Yes, I adding specs test as well. I will give links to them in main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need global variables you can do something like this:

```
result = [:a_0, :b_0, :a_1, :b_1].map do |key|
  value = params[key].to_f
  value % 1 == 0 ? value.to_i : value
end

integer_decimal_converter(*result)
```

Comment: I do not need a global variables, but i need an instance variables.

Comment: You can add `@first_0, @second_0, @first_1, @second_1 = result`